# Direct Sum: Complement

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory, direct-sum

Does every set admit a complement to form a direct sum as: $X=A\oplus A'$
I don't think so and my first guess would be: $X:= \mathbb R$, $A:= \lbrace -1,0,+1\rbrace$
Can somebody proof this? Or give another counterexample? Thx, Alex

Comment: The coproduct in the category of sets is *disjoint union,* usually denoted $A \sqcup B$.  The coproduct in the category of $k$-vector spaces is *direct sum,* denoted $V \oplus W$.

Comment: Well, I'm talking about direct sum not coproduct in general and specifically interested in subsets not necessarily subspaces. Further, I'm thinking about wether every projection not necessarily linear gives rise to a decomposition in that form

Comment: Can explain what *direct sum* means for *sets?*  Do you mean the *symmetric difference* which is sometimes denoted with that symbol $A \oplus B$?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference

Comment: I mean every vector uniquely can be written as sum: $v=a+b$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directness: $A\oplus A'\iff A+a'\cap A+a''=\varnothing$
Completeness: $A+A'=X\iff \bigcup_{a'\in A} A+a'=X$

Counterexample: $A:=B_1(0)$